# Using pandas.pct_change() on dataset results in 'nan' loss in tensorflow model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, tensorflow

Let's say I have a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Inputs': np.arange(100), 'Labels': np.multiply(np.arange(100),5)})
df.head()
```

```
 Inputs Labels
0   0   0
1   1   5
2   2   10
3   3   15
4   4   20
```

For simplicity, let `model` be just one Dense layer with 1 unit and no activation.

Training like so works just fine:

```
model.fit(x=df['Inputs'], y=df['Labels'])
```

But now, if I turn my dataframe into percent changes:

```
pct_change_df = df.pct_change(axis=0)
pct_change_df.head()
```

```
Inputs  Labels
0   NaN NaN
1   inf inf
2   1.000000    1.000000
3   0.500000    0.500000
4   0.333333    0.333333
```

training will result in only `nan` losses. I figured this is due to there being NaN and (possibly) inf values in my dataset which will blow the gradients to infinity or -infinity. However, after removing all of those:

```
# removing inf values from pct_change_df
pct_change_df = pct_change_df.replace([np.inf,-np.inf],np.nan).dropna(axis=0)
pct_change_df.head()
```

```
Inputs  Labels
2   1.000000    1.000000
3   0.500000    0.500000
4   0.333333    0.333333
5   0.250000    0.250000
6   0.200000    0.200000
```

I still get the same results. I have no idea what the issue is.

```
# loss is still nan!!
model.fit(x=pct_change_df['Inputs'], y=pct_change_df['Labels'], epochs=5)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 4/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 5/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer on my own. Stupidly, the example code I wrote out above is exactly the issue, haha.

Indeed, the model will train fine on the actual data, and indeed the model will not train fine on any data that has NaN or inf values in it.

But if you try to train on data with NaN or inf values, then the model will never stop having a `nan` loss, despite if you train it with new, clean data.

Start training the model **only** when you know there are no NaN or inf values in your data.